# Passing Laravel routes to vue components

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, vuex

I have an `index.blade.php` and I included vue codes in this view.
In a normal situation we'll pass the laravel route like so :

`<a href="{{route('some-route')}}"> Link </a>`

Imagine I have a master vue component inside this `index.blade.php` and I'm doing this right now :

```html
@section('body')
    <router-view
        {{-- Props --}}
        prop1  = "{{route('route1')}}"
        prop2  = "{{route('route2')}}"
        prop3  = "{{route('route3')}}"
        prop4    = "{{route('route4')}}"
        prop5    = "{{route('route5')}}"
        prop6    = "{{route('route6')}}"
        prop7    = "{{route('route7')}}"
        ...
    </router-view>
@endsection
```

I have so many routes that I want to use in my vue components and Im doing something like this ...

Sometimes it gets frustrating to write all of these routes and using props and etc.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Route::getRoutes()** this will return RouteCollection this way you can do

```
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

@section('body')
<router-view
    {{-- Props --}}
@foreach(Route::getRoutes() as $key => $route)
    prop{{ $key }} = "{{ $route->getPath() }}"

</router-view>
@endsection
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But there's a point that I forgot to mention and that is, the props (prop1,2,3 ...) are actual names... for example : name, action, productUrl and ...) how can I handle that ?

Comment: can you define what are 'name, productUrl' here ?

Comment: There are different routes for different things. For example define a product, define attributes for product and ... Therefore there are different routes with unique names.